# Mongodb upadate the whole collection according to the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I needs to update the Mongodb whole collection according to the data on my website.

`Schema({ title: "data" }).which_function_should_I_call`

when I call the first time it has 20 data item update the collection 20 documents - collection documents length should be 20.

after the second call data has 5 data item the collection length should be 5 documents.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is "data" an array? And u want to update the first n-documents,which is equal to the length of the "data" items?

Comment: @fractal397 data is a integer

Comment: I'm not confident I understood your question. Can you provide an example and expected output?

Comment: @GytisTG      { "place": "the place",
  "placedescription": "describe about the place", },
  
this is the data which i am expecting

Comment: Something is still missing... Because you could write like `Model.updateMany({ <field>: <value> }, { $set: { <field>: <value> } });` and you would get what you wrote in there :)